# Is it always safe to type [i.e. run Get-Content] on a file in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

Supposedly an attacker sends me a malicious `readme.txt` and I'm going to open PowerShell and run `type readme.txt`.

Can the attacker via any sort of control char sequences or using any other technique cause a non-expected behavior this way?

Answer (score 1):

No, but if its a binary disguised as a text file, you'll just see a bunch of jibberish in the output.

Personally, I'd check the file type prior to running any commands with the file. On *nix machines you can use the `file {filename}` command. For Windows see [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/274734/is-there-a-tool-that-can-determine-the-file-type-from-containing-data) on SuperUser.